# cmap for use with line plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have a list of color values (in either of the formats: hex ('#ffffff') or rgb (255,255,255) if that helps). These colors correspond explicitly with the line segment between points. Currently I plot a line as a collection of line segments via:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import itertools
colors = itertools.cycle('#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ff0320', '#452143', ...)
t = (0, 1, 2, 3, ...)
var1 = (43, 15, 25, 9, ...)
ax = plt.subplot2grid((3,1), (0,0), colspan=3, rowspan=1)

ps = [(t,var1) for (t,var1) in zip(t, val)]
for start, end in zip(ps[:-1], ps[1:]):
    t, var1 = zip(start, end)
    c = next(colors)    
    ax.plot(t, var1, color=c)
```

However since I have a color for each point I would much prefer to set a cmap for the plot. How might I accomplish converting a list of colors into a cmap which I can use when plotting a line?

Comment: What is `foo` in your code?

Comment: foo should be the axis on which to plot. Edited.

Comment: why not just `plt.scatter((0, 1, 2, 3), (43, 15, 25, 9), c=('#ffffff', '#ffffff', '#ff0320', '#452143'))`?

Comment: Some of the points are spaced a large distance from one another so scatter  is not appropriate as I'd like to show a line interpolating that distance.

Comment: You want to use http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection

Comment: Also, please don't put tags in the title, that is what the tags are for.

Answer (score 2):

As **tcaswell** says, use a [`LineCollection`](http://matplotlib.org/api/collections_api.html#matplotlib.collections.LineCollection) for this:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection

# a random walk
xy = np.cumsum(np.random.randn(1000, 2), axis=0)
z = np.linspace(0, 1, 1000)

lc = LineCollection(zip(xy[:-1], xy[1:]), array=z, cmap=plt.cm.hsv)

fig,  ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.add_collection(lc)
ax.margins(0.1)
plt.show()
```

[image]